# Remove old searches

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, search, query

I've modified the search result from the catalogsearch. So the output for a search done today is different from the one done a month ago.

There is a problem when doing a new search and it is that it shows you the same result as I hadn't modified the search result form. It seems it takes the old result to avoid doing the "same" task again.

So the point is, is there any way to make magento override the search result? Because it is good to keep the informatation about the searches people have done in the website and I would like to keep it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so you need to remove search from some attribute.

if you not wish to search on some attribute then you can remove it from

admin->catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes->description  - >Use in Quick Search , Use in Advanced Search
select NO in drop down and clear cash and your search not work on description.

thanks